# Git Push to bitbucket taking forever with only one file

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I'm very new to using Git and am using Bitbucket. I haven't had any issues until a few days ago. Recently my `git push` will take hours even if I'm only using `git add` on one file.

My method for adding files has been `git add -A` which I was told isn't an efficient way to add files to the repository. I am considering just deleting my current repository and creating a new one. My entire site is around 20MB and my hidden `.git` folder is around 4.5GB. Pushing only one file with a size of a megabyte pushes over 3.5GB to bitbucket. Any help would be great. Thanks.

My normal process for adding files to Bitbucket (Just in case you need it):

`git add -A`

`git commit -m "Something about changes"`

`git push`

---

Comment: Yes but in order to add my files to the server I have to `git push`

Comment: Have you already successfully pushed the 3.5GB, or did you cancel the push because it was taking too long? Because if you have already pushed it, it shouldn't take forever after that.

Comment: @DavidDeutsch I've pushed it multiple times. My 'got status' never removes 2 files. One was deleted the other modified.

Comment: What do you mean that it never removes 2 files? What is the output of `git status`?

Comment: @DavidDeutsch before I push it will turn the two committed and added files green. After the push they're back to red and I have to add commit push all over again in an endless loop.

Comment: Hmm, something is not right here; files that have been committed should not show up in `git status` at all; the ones in green are those that have been staged, but not yet committed. And just doing a `git push` should never affect the files listed in `git status`. Is this a public repo that I could take a look at by any chance?

Comment: @DavidDeutsch I can't make it public but I'm not using it for anything other than code storage. I think I'm just going to re create the repo. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never push files. You always push commits.

You first create local commits and then push those commits to the server.

There is no "efficient" way to create commits. Using `git add -A` will probably do exactly the right thing(tm).

If your `.git` directory is much larger than your files, then you most probably have big files in your history. If you commit a big file and delete it in a later commit it will still be stored in your repository.

Have a look at `git log --graph --decorate --name-status HEAD...@{u}` to check how many commits you are trying to push, and which files they change.

Sounds a bit like you added many commits, some of them adding big files.

If this is the case you might use `git rebase -i` to combine some commits.